# Capturing the image from android activity and return to the same activity from where the call to capture image was called

Tags: android

I am new to android.I am developing a survey app in android which will help in taking the survey.In this app i have a field where the picture can be taken of those who is giving the survey.The problem i am facing is as soon as i click the button to capture the image,the image is captured and saved successfully but i am coming out of the survey with certain fields unfilled.Is there any way by which i can return to the same field from where the call to capture the image is given.. Please help

Comment: Have you tried saving your state by overriding onSaveInstanceState on your calling activity?

Comment: tried but it still facing the same problem

Comment: You should provide us with code what you are doing in `onSaveInstanceState` and `onCreate`.

Comment: Do you use a device's camera to take a picture?

Comment: ya i am using device's camera to take the picture

Answer (score 0):

When you capture an image you get a `Bitmap` object which implements `Parcelable` interface which could be put to the `Bundle` of the `Activity`'s `Intent`.

You may call the "capture" `Activity` by [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and after taking a picture return it in the `Intent`'s `Bundle` to the caller `Activity`

For more clarity, you may look through [this](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) tutorial, especially [this](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView) fragment